# How do I block HTTP traffic to a single file address, not the entire domain, without a browser-specific program?

Tags: internet, blocking, minecraft

I like playing an older version of Minecraft, 1.5.2, but there is a newer version available; and at the title screen, there is a nagging message saying that 1.6.2 is available for download. In [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125882/can-you-remove-the-1-6-2-is-available-nag-message-in-older-versions-of-minecra?rq=1) there is an answer saying that you must block the link http://assets.minecraft.net/1_6_has_been_released.flag but not the whole assets.minecraft.net.

How can I block HTTP access to this file, without blocking access to the entire domain or buying any equipment?

Comment: Maybe by asking this on [gaming.se] you can get a better answer, as it is a gaming-centered question?

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy This question was asked on Arqade, and they mentioned SuperUser. It is in my question. Here is the link: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125882/can-you-remove-the-1-6-2-is-available-nag-message-in-older-versions-of-minecra?rq=1

Comment: Ouch. Sorry for my lack of attention!

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy It's fine :) gronostaj's answer isn't working, and all of the other solutions are browser-specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you block specific urls and not entire domain](http://superuser.com/questions/179700/how-do-you-block-specific-urls-and-not-entire-domain)

Comment: @techie007 I'd like an answer that works outside of a web browser, e.g. no extensions/in-browser proxies.

Comment: The only way I know of to do this is with a proxy or content blocking firewall.  You need to have a program that understands HTTP well enough to see what URL you're requesting, and can also block network requests it monitors, and also be configurable enough to know to stop just one website.  That's basically what a proxy or content blocking firewall does.

Comment: @BaconBits If you mind explaining how I could set one up, I will accept it as correct, assuming that's the best (or only) way.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are for humans, not for software - Minecraft doesn't "use a browser", but it doesn't mean it works in a different way. Actually, it's using exactly the same protocol that browsers do: HTTP.

I have two ideas on blocking that file. Both should work, but both will have some side effects.

1. Block port 80 in your firewall. This is **not** a good idea, because it will affect all Java programs, so I'm not going into details. If you want to try it, then you can access Windows Firewall by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing `wf.msc`.
2. Block `http://assets.minecraft.net/` system-wide through your `hosts` file. Open Notepad as Adminstrator (right-click it → *Open as Administrator*), click *File* → *Open* and type `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Open the file and add following line at the end:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 assets.minecraft.net
   ```

   This one has some unpleasant side effects too: none of your programs will be able to connect to that address for any purpose.

Comment: The launcher uses assets.minecraft.net, is there any way I can block the specific file's URL? Perhaps through my router?

Comment: You'd have to check the router settings yourself, it's not a common feature.

Comment: Mine are pretty basic; I'm not sure if they will help.